# Is there a way to change the column widths in termcal?

Tags: formatting, termcal

I'm using termcal to write a course schedule. I have two lecture days and the lecture titles that are very short, like CH1. However, the assignments are generally completed Sunday evenings and have longer titles, like CH1 Graded Homework.

Is there any way to set the width of the lecture days columns to be small and increase the width of the due date column?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{termcal}

\newcommand{\TRClass}{%
\skipday % Monday (no class)
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday} % Tuesday
\skipday % Wednesday (no class)
\calday[Thursday]{\classday} % Thursday
\skipday % Friday 
\skipday
\calday[Sunday]{\classday} % Due day
}

\begin{document}
\begin{calendar}{1/14/2018}{1} 
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.2in}
\TRClass

\caltexton{1}{CH1}   \caltexton{2}{CH2}   \caltexton{3}{DUE: CH2 Graded Homework; Discussion 1}
\end{calendar}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\setlength{\calwidth}{6in}
```

for instance, works for me

Comment: This seems to change the width of all of the columns.  I think OP was looking to have different width columns.

Comment: If that's the OPs situation: can't you save the old value of `\calwidth`, change it and restore it later?